# How to make a 301 Redirect of everything BUT the sitemap

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, sitemap

i created my main landing page with instapages - hence i use a 301 redirect. However, for google webmaster tools i want to host a sitemap on my domain, and avoid that it gets redirected.

so domain.com gets redirected to www.domain.com (which DNS points to instapage page)

domain.com/ => 301 www.domain.com (instapage)
BUT
domain.com/sitemap.xml -> no 301

Thanks

Comment: Where are your current .htaccess rules?

Comment: normal apache. only one redirect: Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative condition based rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^sitemap\.xml$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```